# How to update the module files in an automation account?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation

Is there a way to update the module files in an Automation Account while executing the script?

For Example, I have the below snippet of code to update the module files in my local machine.

```
$path = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\**\*\Framework\Abstracts\**.ps1"
$item = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path"
$Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $item.FullName

$newContent = ""
$Content | ForEach-Object {
if ( $_ -match 'response = ""')
{
"match"
$_ = $_.replace('response = ""', 'response = "y"')
}
$newContent += $($_ + "`r`n" )
}
Set-Content -Value $newContent -LiteralPath $item.FullName
```

Is it possible to run the above script in a runbook to update the automation account modules?

If not, how to update the module files in an automation account while executing the script?

Where are all the modules stored? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't run your script above in a runbook. As we can see, your path includes your own environment variables and local path, which azure cannot recognize.

**For [Import custom modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-modules), there are three ways, you can have a look at this link.**

Actually you can configure modules directly in portal.
Navigate to your automation account, find `Modules` and `Modules gallery` under `Shared Resources`.
[image]
Click the Module you need, such as `Az`. You will see the page below. Then click import.
[image]

Comment: I understand that the azure cannot recognize the local path.  But, where are all the modules stored in an automation account worker? Do we have access to its folder structure?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can have a look at the new link. @VINODKUMAR

Comment: @DorisLv When I try to import the Az module, I get a message listing all of the dependencies and saying they must be installed first. It seems we have to install them all manually!?! Ugh!
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34978
I really hope that's outdated and there's an easier way.

Comment: I'm afraid we have to do it manually in Portal. @ToddRopog